# MySQL add data from one table to another

Tags: mysql

There are 2 connected tables

### `uc_products` with fields

vid
sell_price

### `uc_product_options` with fields

nid
oid
price

and `vid == nid`

I need to get all `prices` from `uc_product_options` and add them to `uc_products` in `sell_price` column.

I know how to select all values I need
`SELECT nid, oid, price FROM uc_product_options WHERE oid = 3;`

but how to combine this query with `UPDATE` query for the second table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Update` ... `join` should help you:

```
UPDATE uc_products a 
    JOIN uc_product_options  b ON a.nid = b.vid 
SET a.sell_price = b.price
where b.oid=3
```

Comment: How should I add condition `WHERE oid = 3` for `uc_product_options`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! Why I can't use `INSERT... SELECT` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html here and need to use JOIN ?

Comment: @Heidel Insert creates a new record in your table. As i understand you you have to update an exisiting record

Comment: Oh, I see, I really need to update existing entries, thanks a lot for explanation!

Comment: oh, there is a little mistype in your answer `SET a.sell_price = b.price`

Answer (score 1):

Update the joined tables

```
update uc_products
join uc_product_options on uc_products.vid = uc_product_options.nid
set uc_products.sell_price_ = uc_product_options.price
where uc_product_options.oid = 3
```

Comment: How should I add condition `WHERE oid = 3` for `uc_product_options`?